# How to count the number of digits in an int value?

Tags: java, arrays

Given the following code.

```
 int[] eg = {21,20,1,12,2}
 public numbers(int[] eg)
 {
     for(int i=0; i < eg.length; i++)
```

I would expect `eg.length` to be 5,  where `eg[0]` would = 21 `eg[1]` would = 20,  `eg[3]` would = 1

I would like to check each element of eg[i] to see if it is a 1 digit or 2 digit number I tried `eg[0].length` to no avail,  but am I correct in assuming that is only for Array Lists?

Answer (score 21):

Convert the number to a String and get the length.

```
int length = String.valueOf(eg[i]).length();
```

Or

```
int length = Integer.valueOf(eg[i]).toString().length();
```

---

Use this mathematical equation (assuming that all the data in the array are strictly positive numbers).

```
int length = (int)(Math.log10(eg[i])+1);
```

Comment: Thank you. cant up vote as im new but this helped.

Comment: Log function will probably fall short if the integer is something like two zeros (00). In that case, the string method is better.

Answer (score 8):

`eg[i]` is of type `int`, which doesn't have the `length` property.

There are many ways of telling how many digits the number has:

- write your own method that accepts an `int` and keeps dividing by 10 until the number reaches 0.
- using math properties:

  `int length = (int) (Math.log10(number) + 1);`
- converting the number to String and using its methods

Comment: Ok thanks a lot understand it now, would upvote but cant atm!!!

Comment: @30iT I'm glad it helped. Never mind the upvote, when you'll get the privilege you'll be able to. It's more important that you understood the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see what is the number length, MChaker's solution is the correct one. However, if you want to see if the number contains one digit or more than one digit, then you might consider the following solution:

```
public class NumberTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] eg = {21,20,1,12,2, -3, -8, -20};
    System.out.println("Array Length: " + eg.length);

    for(int i=0; i < eg.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("#" + i + ": Value: " + eg[i] + " one digit number: " + isOneDigitNumber(eg[i]));
    }
}
static private boolean isOneDigitNumber(int number) {
    return (-10 < number && number < 10);
}
```

}

and here is the result of above code:

```
Array Length: 8
#0: Value: 21 one digit number: false
#1: Value: 20 one digit number: false
#2: Value: 1 one digit number: true
#3: Value: 12 one digit number: false
#4: Value: 2 one digit number: true
#5: Value: -3 one digit number: true
#6: Value: -8 one digit number: true
#7: Value: -20 one digit number: false
#7: Value: -20 one digit number: false
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an algorithm used in JDK which is probably the fastest one:

```
final static int [] sizeTable = { 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999,
                                  99999999, 999999999, Integer.MAX_VALUE };

// Requires positive x
static int stringSize(int x) {
    for (int i=0; ; i++)
        if (x <= sizeTable[i])
            return i+1;
}
```

Comment: looks like a few ways to skin a cat...but i am not sure i fully understand this implementation